# Pass JSON array as parameter using chimera.json

Tags: json, delphi, delphi-xe2

im new to JSON and php and IOS development using Delphi XE2.

i want to parse a JSON array which i get from the php script
          http://returnjson.ap01.aws.af.cm/returnjson.php

when this is opened i get the array as

```
 [{"cname":"MAAO"},{"cname":"MAIM"}]
```

i have installed this parser from http://arcana.sivv.com/chimera
and a code sample is here

```
 procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
  i : integer;
  obj : IJSONObject;
  begin
 obj := JSON('{"firstname":"leonard",'+
          ' "lastname":"nimoy",'+
          ' "email":['+
          '   "spock@enterprise.com",'+
          '   "lazydude@mars.com"]'+
          '}');
  Writeln(obj['firstname']);
  for i := 0 to obj.Arrays['email'].count-1 do
 begin
   Writeln(obj.Arrays['email'][i]);
  // StringGrid1.Cells[0,i]:=obj.Arrays['email'][i];
 end;

 obj['lastname'] := 'shatner';
 writeln(obj.AsJSON);
 ReadLn;
 end;
```

can any one tell me how to pass the json array from the 
  http://returnjson.ap01.aws.af.cm/returnjson.php
to  `obj : IJSONObject;` ?

Comment: Why you are not using the [DBXJSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Data.DBXJSON) unit?

Comment: DBX.JSON performs very poorly. Chimera was written for speed and fills in some usage holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use some way of obtaining the data from the webserver.  I use [TMS](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/) web software components. I do not use XE2 so not sure if there is a native component to do this.

I used their webdata component to do something similar.  Drop a webdata component on the form and then the code from the examples:-

```
with webdata1.Data.Add do
begin
  scanfirst := '<span id="yfs_l10';
  scanfrom := '">';
  scanto := '</';
  url := 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s='+quotes+'&d=v1';
end;
end;

  webdata1.Execute;


  for i := 1 to stringgrid1.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
     stringgrid1.Cells[2,i] := webdata1.Data.Items[i - 1].Data;
  end;
```